# How to typeset the Glagolitic script in LaTeX? (ⰳⰾⰰⰳⱁⰾⰹⱌⰰ, глаголица)

Tags: fonts, examples

I am looking for an example of a LaTeX document written in the [Glagolitic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glagolitic_script).

(I am aware of the [croatian package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/croatian), but was not able to use it.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're willing to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you just need to find an OpenType or TrueType font that supports Glagolitic.

On my machine I have two of them. The Noto fonts can be downloaded for free, as far as I know, from https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Glagolitic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontface{\glagoliticA}{Menaion Unicode}
\newfontface{\glagoliticB}{NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/,
]

\begin{document}

{\glagoliticA ⰳⰾⰰⰳⱁⰾⰹⱌⰰ} (глаголица)

{\glagoliticB ⰳⰾⰰⰳⱁⰾⰹⱌⰰ} (глаголица)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On my system there are a few more fonts that support the required glyphs:  FreeSerif, Segoe UI Historic, and Shafarik.

Comment: ...and you can always try `albatross ⰾ` ;-) (Thanks Paulo...)

Comment: @Rmano I recall the name *paulo*, did we have a competetion/show-off